# Alternatives to BizTalk as a rules engine

Tags: biztalk, rule-engine, biztalk-rule-engine

My customer wants a end-user configurable rules engine. Currently they are considering BizTalk. Are their any other alternatives that they should consider?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61437/what-are-some-viable-alternatives-to-biztalk-server

Comment: Not really. I am specifically interested in rules engines, not the rest of BizTalk's functionality.

Comment: Have a look at [FlexRule](http://www.flexrule.com). It is written fully in .NET and you can handle all different rules and logic: Procedural, Validation, Inference(RETE), Flow, Decision table, Workflow...

Answer (score 4):

InRule makes an interesting looking rules engine, but I have no idea on the price: http://www.inrule.com/

Review and some screenshots here:
http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/09/19/review-of-inrule-v-4.0-business-rule-authoring-system.aspx

Comment: 1) The review link is broken

Comment: That geekswithblogs.net site may no longer be online... either way my 10 year old review is probably not relevant anymore.... :)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [Windows Workflow based rules engine](http://www.enigmasupercomputing.com/RulesEngine).  It allows a programmer to layout the basic rule repository (storage and interface) and has a rehosted workflow designer to allow business analysts to define rules.

It currently doesn't implement forward or backward chaining of rules so the rules are only executed from top-to-bottom in order (I guess you could argue that this means it's not *technically* a rules engine yet).

I like to keep it simple so if you don't need the rule chaining check it out.

Comment: If you want some free advertising on InfoQ send me an email at jonathan@infoq.com. I have ways to promote projects like yours using interviews and educational articles.

Answer (score 2):

Depends if you are looking for windows/.net only or if Java is also an option. Drools is an open source rules engine with a web based rules authoring environment (as well as an IDE) that implements both forward and backward chaining, as well as support to CEP (Complex Event Processing):

http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-guvnor.html

It is open source, and free. If you need support with SLA, Red Hat productizes it as the JBoss BRMS product:

http://www.redhat.com/products/jbossenterprisemiddleware/business-rules/

Comment: There is also Drools.NET http://droolsdotnet.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 1):

.Net Framework has a basic rules engine as part of what is considered Windows Workflow.  Coupled with the sample applications (including an almost-usable rule editor using a SQL backend), this can provide basic rule engine functionality.

We are successfully using it in a web project with hundreds of business rules without using any other Windows Workflow features.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349785.aspx